# need explanation on subscript out of bound error in R

Tags: r, subscript

I'm having an odd problem.
I'm using a for loop to run a code from day 2 to day 365. I didnot put code here because it's a long code.

When I run this code, it gives me the error after a while: subscript out of bounds.

It will appear once at day 77 (or any other day), and when rerun, it will run through that day this time, with the error appearing later or earlier. I double-checked the code; everything appears to be in order, and the matrix values are within the acceptable range from where this error appears.
Is anyone able to explain why this is happening? I can get up to 365 by rerunning whenever an error occurs, but not all at once.

Comment: We can't really help you without seeing your code.  What I'd suggest is that you comment out everything unrelated to the error until you have a short program you can post here, then copy to a new file, delete all those commented-out lines, and post what's left.  But I think you might find that you spot the error yourself when you look at it that closely.

Comment: Perhaps run it through `flow` package.